# Passive forms in English

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

From what I know perfect continuous tenses don't have a passive form , but could we construct a sentence using the same structure as perfect continuous tenses , I mean instead of 'be' we can put 'get' in the sentence , now I ain't saying that the meaning of the sentence would remain the same .

For example -

1. I have been getting bullied by my classmates for as long as I can remember .

Now this sentence doesn't sound incorrect to me , but I could be wrong . Would you please let me know if this is grammatically correct?

Comment: Please don't use the word "aint".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct, and to my Canadian ears, totally natural.

In fact, you can make passive sentences with perfect continuous tenses, but "been being" sounds very awkward, and the non-continuous alternative (just the perfect tense) usually has the same meaning without the awkwardness. It's so uncommon in English that textbooks say the form doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly grammatical. It's rather awkward, and so I don't think it's very likely, but I can certainly imagine somebody saying it.

Comment: Doesn't sound awkward to me.  Except or maybe the uncontracted "I have."